# Can I make a plot legend show box plots using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend-properties

I'm using an unconventional method to convey data using box plots; however, it isn't immediately obvious that the plot is showing box plots instead of a distribution. Therefore, I'd like to make the plot legend show little color-coded box plots (right now it shows lines). Is there a way to do this?

I am currently using a custom legend made by creating several Line2D objects. I'd love a way to make a custom legend with little box plots instead of lines.

Comment: A boxplot symbol would be a rectangle, one line through its center and two small lines perpendicular to that line at the line's tips.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was hoping that wouldn't be the only solution because I don't have a lot of matplotlib experience to be able to create that little masterpiece.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sure I can make those pieces separately, but how do I put the lines & rectangle together to make one object?

Comment: For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804479/4124317) you have many lines in a single legend entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the answer from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804479/1356000) and [some hack I wrote a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52335974/1356000), I've created a legend handler that draws a boxplot. It gets its color from a Line2D artist, which may or may not be appropriate depending on your use case.

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase

class HandlerBoxPlot(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                   xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize,
                   trans):
        a_list = []
        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0])*width-xdescent, 
                                              np.array([0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25])*height-ydescent)) # box

        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0.5,0.5])*width-xdescent,
                                              np.array([0.75,1])*height-ydescent)) # top vert line

        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0.5,0.5])*width-xdescent,
                                              np.array([0.25,0])*height-ydescent)) # bottom vert line

        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0.25,0.75])*width-xdescent,
                                              np.array([1,1])*height-ydescent)) # top whisker

        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0.25,0.75])*width-xdescent,
                                              np.array([0,0])*height-ydescent)) # bottom whisker

        a_list.append(matplotlib.lines.Line2D(np.array([0,1])*width-xdescent,
                                              np.array([0.5,0.5])*height-ydescent, lw=2)) # median
        for a in a_list:
            a.set_color(orig_handle.get_color())
        return a_list

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l1, = ax.plot([0,1],[0,1],c='C0')
l2, = ax.plot([1,0],[0,1],c='C1')

ax.legend([l1,l2], ["legend 1", "legend 2"], handler_map={l1:HandlerBoxPlot(), l2:HandlerBoxPlot()}, handleheight=3)
```

[image]